# qt: How to animate the transparency of a child QPushButton using QPropertyAnimation?

Tags: qt, animation

I want to progressively decrease the opacity of a QPushButton over a time of 2 seconds to complete transparency. For that I used the QPropertyAnimation class and used the property "windowOpacity" of the button to achieve the effect. But that worked only for a standalone QPushButton. When I assigned a parent to the button, the effect disappeared. Is there any way of achieving the same effect for child buttons ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `windowOpacity` property only applies to top level windows so it won't help you with animating transparency on child widgets unfortunately.

Standard controls are a bit problematic as well as there are many considerations contributing to their final appearance. There are many approaches you could take but they will all involve a certain amount of coding. There is no easy way :)

To set the transparency of a `QPushButton`, you would need to either set a stylesheet for it, or change some of the properties of the palette. Since neither of these options are directly usable by a `QPropertyAnimation`, you can create your own custom property and animate that.

Below is some code that specifies a custom property for a `MainWindow` called `alpha`. The alpha value is used to set the alpha portion of the button color. With this property in place, we can use `QPropertyAnimation` to animate it. The result is a button that fades in and out. This only handles the buttons background and not the text but it should provide a starting point for you.

**MainWindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int alpha READ alpha WRITE setAlpha);

public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

private:
    int m_alpha;
    QPushButton * m_button1, *m_button2;

    int alpha() const;
    void setAlpha(const int a_alpha);
};

#endif  /* MAINWINDOW_H */
```

**MainWindow.cpp:** *(Updated to include stylesheet transparency example)*

```
#include <QPlastiqueStyle>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow() :
    m_button1(0),
    m_button2(0),
    m_alpha(255)
{
    resize(200, 200);
    QPalette windowPalette(palette());
    windowPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, QBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0)));
    setPalette(windowPalette);

    m_button1 = new QPushButton(this);
    m_button1->setText("Palette Transparency");
    m_button1->setAutoFillBackground(false);
    // NOTE: Changing the button background color does not work with XP Styles
    // so we need to use a style that allows it.
    m_button1->setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle());

    m_button2 = new QPushButton(this);
    m_button2->move(0, 50);
    m_button2->setText("Stylesheet Transparency");
    m_button2->setAutoFillBackground(false);
    m_button2->setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle());

    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "alpha");
    animation->setDuration(1000);
    animation->setKeyValueAt(0, 255);
    animation->setKeyValueAt(0.5, 100);
    animation->setKeyValueAt(1, 255);
    animation->setLoopCount(-1);
    animation->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

int MainWindow::alpha() const
{
    return m_alpha;
}

void MainWindow::setAlpha(const int a_alpha)
{
    m_alpha = a_alpha;

    QPalette buttonPalette(m_button1->palette());
    QColor buttonColor(buttonPalette.button().color());
    buttonColor.setAlpha(m_alpha);
    buttonPalette.setBrush(QPalette::Button, QBrush(buttonColor));
    m_button1->setPalette(buttonPalette);

    QString stylesheet("background-color: rgba(0,200,0," + QString::number(m_alpha) + ");");
    m_button2->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);

}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow m;
    m.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but not if I set the color through a stylesheet. Any hint as to what functions to manipulate in order to make the borders and the text also transparent ?

Comment: Everything you should need is available in the documentation for QPalette. There is a lot there but some reading and experimenting with the code I provided will get you there. That's all I did :)

Comment: I've updated the example code to include a button with stylesheet based transparency since you mentioned that you couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a while ago and came to basically the same solution(manipulating the controls palette). But, while the helper property in the MainWindow is surely a quick and easy solution, it's a dirty one too. So, at least for larger and reoccurring usage it seamed much more appropriate to create a new animation class covering those needs. This isn't much more code(simply inherit QAbstractAnimation, move that palette stuff in there and pass the target control as a parameter into that class) but it keeps your parent control(like the mainwindow-class) free from such animation implementation details which surely don't belong in there.