# Is it possible to set the opacity of qt widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, opacity, qwidget

I know that there is a function `QWidget::setWindowOpacity(qreal level)` but as written in the documentation this does only work for windows.

Is there a way to make widgets that are lying inside layouts opaque too?

What I'm trying to do is an animation where widgets are fading in. I once did that with a preferences-dialog and there it worked.

So do you think there is a way or a work-around to achieve opacity for widgets inside layouts? How would you do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have no background under widget, maybe you can change widget color starting from background color.

Comment: There is a similar question [Animate transparency..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953382/qt-how-to-animate-the-transparency-of-a-child-qpushbutton-using-qpropertyanimat) with a code example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use QGraphicsOpacityEffect in order to achieve this effect.

- Qt4: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html
- Qt5: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html
- Qt6: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html

Answer (score 11):

Well for widgets inside mainwidow appear to have `setAutoFillBackground(False)` by default.

to make it fade in fadeout u need to to use `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` along with `setAutoFillBackground(True)`

a small example: write inside the widget which is called inside the mainwindow

```
op=QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self)
op.setOpacity(1.00) #0 to 1 will cause the fade effect to kick in
self.setGraphicsEffect(op)
self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Comment: Setting `setAutoFillBackground` on a child of a central widget did the trick for me: opacity effect now works for the widget. Any idea why setting that is required?

Answer (score 4):

`SetWindowOpacity` works for me in Linux. I used code like this to change window opacity, (value is from 0 to 100):

```
setWindowOpacity(qreal(value)/100);
```

Comment: This works for windows, but not for widgets which are part of a layout etc. At least for me, I am using Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstanded. I though you mean MS Windows xD

Answer (score 3):

```
mywidget.setStyleSheet('background-color:rgba(r, g, b, alpha);')
```

works for me

Comment: Please look at formatting the code in your answer to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt5 you can use css to make widgets transparent

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDialog dialog;
    dialog.setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("#LolButton{color: transparent; background-color: transparent;}"));
    QPushButton button(&dialog);
    button.setText("Button");
    button.setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LolButton"));
    QObject::connect(&button,&QPushButton::clicked,[](){
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("LolButton omg");
        msg.exec();
    });
    dialog.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]