# QT pushbutton with image how to transparent/opacity

Tags: qt, qtgui

I have a pushbutton and was styled in QSS to assign an image like this

```
QPushButton[type="buttonImgType"] {
    image: url(:images/svg/myIcon.svg);
    image-position: center;
    min-height: 42px;
    min-width: 130px;
}
```

I want this button to display as if it is faded or like say 50% transparent when it is not checked
and show full image when it is. But I cant find a way how to using the properties in QT for buttons.

Anyone have idea how to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ over Qt : Controlling transparency of Labels and Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948453/c-over-qt-controlling-transparency-of-labels-and-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Style :**

```
QPushButton
{
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;

}
QPushButton:pressed
{
   background-color:rgba(239, 41, 41,50);
   border:2px solid black;
}
```

until QPushButton has  border it didn't transparent .