# Smooth screen transition using QT

Tags: python, qt, animation, widget, transition

I'm currently learning QT, and I'm wondering if it's possible to create an animation like in the ubuntu installer.

[image: Ubuntu installer design]

As you can see on the screenshot, you can switch between 'images' using the left and right arrows. Each time you click on it, a smooth transition is executed.
I would like to know if it's possible to create this kind of design with QT, and if it's possible to replace the 'images' by a widget with various controls inside.

The main goal is to keep the cross-platform compatibility (I'm coding using Python), so I would like to avoid using a third -party library.

Regards,

Comment: The links provided in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4499488/2319400 may be helpful.

Comment: I already dug this link, I'm looking for movement not opacity

Comment: Oops, I thought "smooth transition" would refer to one image fading out while the new one fades in. Within Qt I'd guess you can nevertheless use  the animation framework. Instead of opacity you can probably animate the `geometry` or `x`/`y`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html#animating-qt-properties

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu installer, they use HTML, CSS and JavaScript, you can do the same using [QWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html).

You can even connect Javascript functions to Qt events, that is what you need for make the slides pass every time you press a button or key on the keyboard.

An idea:

Make your slides images, and build a webpage that shows those images. You can use a JavaScript timer to set the time between slides. Then the only you hav to done is add a QWebView control to render that page.

**I don't want to have images, but a widget with controls in it...**

In that case I recommend you to take a look to the [QT Animation Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html), it is very powerful and very easy to use.

Comment: As I said in my first post, I don't want to have images, but a widget with controls in it...