# QAnimation framework: which property to use here

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

Latest Qt Creator has a animation effect on start , the widget shows from darker to lighter , I don't know which property I should use with Qt's animation framework , to make something similar ?

**UPDATE**

Ok , i tried to use windowOpacity animation:

```
QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity", this);
connect(anim, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(animationFinished()));

anim->setDuration(1000);
anim->setStartValue(0.0);
anim->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuad);
anim->setEndValue(1.0);

anim->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

But , when I disabled "Display compositing" in XFWM4 , the effect wasn't working , but QtCreator still have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of [properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QWidget.html#properties)

Maybe you are looking for the windowOpacity one?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953382/qt-how-to-animate-the-transparency-of-a-child-qpushbutton-using-qpropertyanimat) question/answer might help you